# Blank Round Circle on Apple Developer Program Team Roles

Tags: ios, apple-developer

What does this blank circle means on Apple Developer Program Team Roles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

● -- It indicates access "Available" for specified role  and 
○ -- This indicates "Access requires Xcode 7 or later."

Here is reference document by Apple: [Program Roles and iTunes Connect Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)

[image]